# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager JSON data to Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 to make a POST request to my web service that returns JSON data.

```
{
    post =         {
        "first_name" = Joe;
        "last_name" = Blogs;
        "user_id" = 1;
    };
},
    {
    post =         {
        "first_name" = Bill;
        "last_name" = Gates;
        "user_id" = 2;
    };
}
```

Im able to print out responseObject to the console fine which displays my JSON data.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"user": @"root"};
[manager POST:@"http://192.168.0.100/webservice.php" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSString *responseString = [operation responseString];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                     JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                     options:kNilOptions
                     error:&error];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in json)
    {
        NSString *firstName = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"post"] valueForKey:@"first_name"];
        NSLog(@"%@", firstName);
        NSString *lastName = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"post"] valueForKey:@"last_name"];
        NSLog(@"%@", lastName);
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Each "post" is going to be used for a table cell on my View Controller. Im struggling to understand how to make each post an object in an array. Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE

You can use this code snipped to perform your desired functionality:

```
        NSString *responseString = [operation responseString];
        NSData *data= [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray* results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&error];
             for (int i=0; i<results.count; i++)
             {
                 NSDictionary *res=[results objectAtIndex:i];
                 NSDictionary *res2=[res objectForKey:@"post"];
                 [self.storesArray addObject:res2];

             }
             [self.tableView reloadData];
```

and in your `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method, use this code snipped to show data on your cell:

```
NSDictionary *res=[self.storesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.firstName.text=[res objectForKey:@"first_name"];
cell.lastName.text=[res objectForKey:@"last_name"];
```

This `NSDictionary` works in key values pair style, so you can get the value of any key by just mentioning the key name and get the values of that key.

Comment: I added NSMutableArray *storesArray; With your code I'm now getting the following error 2014-01-02 18:26:00.839 Guestlister[1477:70b] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1094bfc00
2014-01-02 18:26:00.840 Guestlister[1477:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1094bfc00'

Comment: It does not like this line.  NSArray* results = [responseObject objectForKey:@"post"];